# Horizontal scrollbar and width auto

Tags: html, css

I have some html content styled with CSS and filled with JS.
At some point, I have a footer with divs contaning external links. Depending on the context, the number of available links may vary, so I want the footer to adjust its width to the number of links, and show an horizontal scrollbar when required.

The trick I have find is to set a container with a 200% width in my footer. However, that code always displays the scrollbar in IE8, when it is working fine in Chrome.

Do you have any idea or advice so the scrollbar only appears when required in IE ? I'd like to get rid of the 300% width in the container, but removing it hides the links outside the screen...

Here is a piece of the code I am using:

```css
div#BottomMenu
{
 width : 99%; 
 height: 150px;
 border-top: 4px solid #E5E5E5; 
 overflow-x: auto; 
 overflow-y: hidden;   
 
}
div#MenuContainer
{ 
 width: 300%; 
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-right:5px;  
}

a.Item
{ 
 float: left; 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family:Helvetica;  
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none; 
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 color:white;
 text-align: center;  
 width: 160px;
 height: 120px;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */  
    vertical-align:middle;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;     
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

a.Item:hover
{
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="MenuContainer">
    <a class="Item" id="link1" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>
    <a class="Item" id="link2" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>
    <a class="Item" id="link3" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>    
    <a class="Item" id="link4" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>    
    <a class="Item" id="link5" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>    
    <a class="Item" id="link6" image:url(./images/Link1.png); background-color: transparent;></a>    
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x` is only supported in IE9 and later.

According to this MSDN article, you can use `-ms-overflow-x` in IE8 as a synonym for this attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms530826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx